# np. max() not showing result inside 'if' in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have been trying to get the first value above a certain threshold from my imported CSV files. when I use `np.where()` I only get the index number where th value crosses the threshold for the first time but not the value itself. I tried to print it using `df.iloc[]` but it didn't work even by giving the index number directly. I did `df.iloc[Index_Abs_Ax]` and `df.iloc[1000]`, where Index_Abs_Ax is the variable where the index number 1000 was stored. But there is an error: *No axis named 60081 for object type DataFrame*

Second thing is that some maximum values in the CSV file are below the threshold. So in this case I want to cut the threshold in half. For that I use an if statement like : `if threshold_abs > np.max(resA_x1)` then divide threshold by 2. But I can error saying : *Invalid Syntax*.

So I would like to know the following 3 things:

1. How can I get the values itself which are above threshold and not just the index number?
2. why the if statement is not working
3. Is there a better way to write the if statements to do the same thing? Maybe use a 'for' ?

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pathlib import Path 

global df
df = pd.DataFrame([])

def function_plot(x,y,z,v,Plot_ShareY=True):    #x,y,z,v are filenames for the same drop height 
    data_1 = Path(x)                            #stores the relative path location
    data_2 = Path(y)
    data_3 = Path(z)
    data_4 = Path(v)
    print(data_1)                               #prints the file location for each input argument
    print(data_2)
    print(data_3)
    print(data_4)
    
    x1 = pd.read_csv(data_1, delimiter=";", skiprows=(1), decimal = ",", na_values = ['no info', '.'])  #loads the csv file from the path created above
    y1 = pd.read_csv(data_2, delimiter=";", skiprows=(1), decimal = ",", na_values = ['no info', '.'])
    z1 = pd.read_csv(data_3, delimiter=";", skiprows=(1), decimal = ",", na_values = ['no info', '.'])
    v1 = pd.read_csv(data_4, delimiter=";", skiprows=(1), decimal = ",", na_values = ['no info', '.'])
    
    time1 = x1.iloc[:,0]                       #stores time values of each file
    time2 = y1.iloc[:,0]
    time3 = z1.iloc[:,0]
    time4 = v1.iloc[:,0]
    
    resA_x1 = x1.iloc[:,1]                      #stores sensor output values for each sensor from each file
    resB_x1 = x1.iloc[:,2]
    resC_x1 = x1.iloc[:,3]
    resD_x1 = x1.iloc[:,4]
    
    resA_y1 = y1.iloc[:,1]
    resB_y1 = y1.iloc[:,2]
    resC_y1 = y1.iloc[:,3]
    resD_y1 = y1.iloc[:,4]
    
    resA_z1 = z1.iloc[:,1]
    resB_z1 = z1.iloc[:,2]
    resC_z1 = z1.iloc[:,3]
    resD_z1 = z1.iloc[:,4]
    
    resA_v1 = v1.iloc[:,1]
    resB_v1 = v1.iloc[:,2]
    resC_v1 = v1.iloc[:,3]
    resD_v1 = v1.iloc[:,4]
    
    threshold_abs = 0.03
    if threshold_abs > np.max(resA_x1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resB_x1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resC_x1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resD_x1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resA_y1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resB_y1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resC_y1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resD_y1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resA_z1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resB_z1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resC_z1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resD_z1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resA_v1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resB_v1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resC_v1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    elif threshold_abs > np.max(resD_v1)        
        threshold_abs = threshold_abs/2         
        print(threshold_abs)
    
        
    Index_Abs_Ax = np.where(resA_x1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]           #prints the first index where the condition holds 
    Index_Abs_Bx = np.where(resB_x1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]
    Index_Abs_Cx = np.where(resC_x1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]
    Index_Abs_Dx = np.where(resD_x1 > threshold_abs) [0][0] 
    
    print(Index_Abs_Ax)
    location = df.iloc(Index_Abs_Ax)
              
    Index_Abs_Ay = np.where(resA_y1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]           #prints the first index where the condition holds 
    Index_Abs_By = np.where(resB_y1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]
    Index_Abs_Cy = np.where(resC_y1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]
    Index_Abs_Dy = np.where(resD_y1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]
            
    Index_Abs_Az = np.where(resA_z1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]           #prints the first index where the condition holds 
    Index_Abs_Bz = np.where(resB_z1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]
    Index_Abs_Cz = np.where(resC_z1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]
    Index_Abs_Dz = np.where(resD_z1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]
            
    Index_Abs_Av = np.where(resA_v1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]           #prints the first index where the condition holds 
    Index_Abs_Bv = np.where(resB_v1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]
    Index_Abs_Cv = np.where(resC_v1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]
    Index_Abs_Dv = np.where(resD_v1 > threshold_abs) [0][0]  
    
    location_x1 = print(Index_Abs_Ax, Index_Abs_Bx, Index_Abs_Cx, Index_Abs_Dx)
    location_y1 = print(Index_Abs_Ay, Index_Abs_By, Index_Abs_Cy, Index_Abs_Dy)
    location_z1 = print(Index_Abs_Az, Index_Abs_Bz, Index_Abs_Cz, Index_Abs_Dz)
    location_v1 = print(Index_Abs_Av, Index_Abs_Bv, Index_Abs_Cv, Index_Abs_Dv)
        
    fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3, ax4) = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize=(12,8))              #plots figure with 4 plots
    fig.suptitle('Drops at 1 cm')   
    
    ax1.plot(time1, resA_x1, 'r', resB_x1, 'g', resC_x1, 'b', resD_x1, 'y')
    
    ax1.set_ylabel('A [V]')
       
    ax2.plot(time2, resA_y1, 'r', resB_y1, 'g', resC_y1, 'b', resD_y1, 'y')
    
    ax2.set_ylabel('B [V]') 
    
    ax3.plot(time3, resA_z1, 'r', resB_z1, 'g', resC_z1, 'b', resD_z1, 'y')
    
    ax3.set_ylabel('C [V]')
    
    ax4.plot(time4, resA_v1, 'r', resB_v1, 'g', resC_v1, 'b', resD_v1, 'y')
    
    ax4.set_xlabel('Time [ms]')
    ax4.set_ylabel('D [V]') 
   
    plt.show()   
    
#function for plotting called   
function_plot('above-1-cm-A1-3.csv','above-1-cm-B2-1.csv', 'above-1-cm-C3-1.csv', 'above-1-cm-D4-1.csv')
```

Comment: I think you should try to understand the concept of loops. Your code is completely overblown with repeated tasks that you seem to apply to 4 different inputs. Why don't you use loops to do that?

Comment: I was going to use loops after I get the output that I wanted. So I was first trying to get it

Comment: You should provide a minimal example showing the issue, rather than a blind paste of your code.

Comment: Thanks, will keep in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy offers many [advanced ways of indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).
If you have an array of indices, such as from `numpy.when` in your example, you can use that array itself as an index to get the corresponding values:

```python
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.random.randint(1, 1000, size=32)
>>> data
array([356,  32, 543, 787, 690, 837, 728,  66, 782, 836, 273, 696, 831,
       589, 641, 705,  42, 812, 664,  78, 323, 286, 106, 256,  97, 152,
        53, 486, 578, 310, 459, 632])
>>> threshold = 800
>>> above = np.where(data > threshold)
>>> above
(array([ 5,  9, 12, 17]),)
>>> data[above]
array([837, 836, 831, 812])
```

As to why `if` statements are not working, it looks like you are simply missing the colon after the condition clause:

```python
>>> if 2 > 1:
...     print('2 > 1')
... 
2 > 1
```

**Update**: The above should normally work with multi-dimensional `numpy` arrays too:

```python
>>> data = np.random.random(size=(10, 3))
>>> data
array([[0.569567  , 0.62124998, 0.88555157],
       [0.66075234, 0.78935382, 0.18876415],
       [0.69428287, 0.0953168 , 0.38439925],
       [0.95652594, 0.15582194, 0.53464335],
       [0.45203105, 0.63865219, 0.55559562],
       [0.49136462, 0.15233917, 0.5780308 ],
       [0.22046296, 0.77791941, 0.1071748 ],
       [0.60487268, 0.09086179, 0.37343351],
       [0.30512539, 0.18934912, 0.5882598 ],
       [0.95298127, 0.25708113, 0.53816788]])
>>> above = np.nonzero(data > 0.9)
>>> above
(array([3, 9]), array([0, 0]))
>>> data[above]
array([0.95652594, 0.95298127])
```

Furthermore, if you are only interested in values, you may also be able to simplify the problem by [flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html)ing the data prior to analysis.

Your last sub-question is quite broad, as there are many ways to generalize and DRY a series of conditional statements. Maybe this could be better off as a separate question?

Comment: Thank you ! Would this also work for a multidimensional array? something like 200000 rows and 5 columns ?

Comment: I am getting an error as '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float' as I have a df of 200000 times 5

Comment: @lqope54 I don't know -- it might depend on the container type of your array (?)

It does work for me with a multidimensional `numpy.ndarray` (updated the answer).